# Generating a FASTMM report WITHOUT the shutdown dialog

Tags: delphi, fastmm

I would like my Delphi project to generate the a FASTMM memory leak report during the program runtime, if possible, and append to that report on shutdown, without having to see [this dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OaZu.jpg) every time I close the program.

If it is not possible to make FMM create the report and edit it N times during runtime, I would at least like to get rid of the annoying dialog, since I already have the report with much more details than the dialog shows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting `SuppressMessageBoxes` to `False`. This capability is only available if you are using the full version of FastMM as opposed to the cut-down version bundled with Delphi.

You cannot call `CheckBlocksOnShutdown` because it is not declared in the interface section of the unit. You could modify the source code for `FastMM4.pas` to make it available. However, calling it whilst your program is running will likely yield nothing useful. That will just spit out a report containing all the memory blocks that are currently allocated. Which is quite different from a list of blocks that have been leaked.

Comment: The full `FastMM` versions are at http://sourceforge.net/projects/fastmm/files/FastMM%204.x%20Stable%20Releases/

Comment: +1 for getting rid of the dialog. Is it possible to call the fastMM4.CheckBlocksOnShutdown at will? That was the other half of the question:) I guess I'll just make a button and try to call that procedure.